# How can I implement a view which has a text and tagged text under it in android?

Tags: android, textview

Looks to be very simple but is there any built in way of implementing this ?
Basically first line as title and message with low font under it which would like a tag-line.

Attached is for password case but the star can be normal letters as well.

[image]

Comment: Please look at https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Working-with-the-EditText