# Is it possible to float the edittext hint to bottom instead of top in android text input layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

Initially, the `edittext` should be shown like this.

Initial `EditText`

[image: Initial EditText]

After clicking on `edittext`, Hint should float to bottom like this -

Required Output

[image: Required Output]

Please help me out in this.

Comment: just put another TextView under your EditText

Comment: Post your xml code

Comment: but the requirement is.. it should be like a floating edittext which floats hint to bottom.

Comment: See this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891482/show-helper-text-below-edittext-along-with-the-hint

Answer (score 0):

You can use any one of the below two methods, but this will float to top on click of hint -

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <EditText..../>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Or

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: But I need to float the hint to bottom

Comment: i believe that is not possible

Answer (score 0):

```
       <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel"
         >

         <EditText
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:ems="10"
             android:width="100dp"
             android:hint="HInt Here"
             android:inputType="text"
             android:clickable="false"
             android:focusable="false"
             android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
             />
     </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Add style to style.xml

```
    <style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
    <item name="android:textSize">11sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#929292</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#929292</item>
    <item name="android:color">#929292</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">bottom</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: It is not working. I need the hint to be moved to bottom of edittext